# calculate total time in FullCalendar v4

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a FullCalendar with several recurring events. 
After initial load and after every event update, I want to calculate the total time of all visible events.
Normally, I would do this when a `renderComplete` event is triggered but there is no such handler in FullCalendar.
Is there another way to accomplish this?